# How to Secure iframe source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web application where i have call some asp pages link in iframe.
 I  want to hide source URL with parameter .Because the URL and parameter Data is confidential. **I just want to hide the iframe source** . I  don't use inspect element disable JavaScript , because using firebug we can easily see the URL source. Please help me.

Comment: You cannot do that. The client has to make an HTTP request to your secret URL, so one way or another it's always possible to discover what that URL is.

Comment: so you want to hide your HTML. Best you can do is obfuscate it somehow, but even then it isn't hidden or protected, just harder to read

Comment: Thanks.. Can I encrypt My URL Link.

Comment: Even if you encrypt it.... it still will be known....

Comment: not really, you could change it to the escaped values EX: any.email@domain.com ->
&#97;&#110;&#121;&#46;&#101;&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#64;&#100;&#111;
&#109;&#97;&#105;&#110;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109  but that's really easy to turn back

Comment: How can i change it to escape value ? # SaggingRufus

Comment: I would try googling it myself

Comment: If you encrypt it using a key and a timestamp, then decrypt and check the timestamp, if the timestamp is within a few seconds of the decrypted timestamp (latency) and it has the key in it, then allow it to load.  That way, every time you load the iframe, the URL is different

Comment: If i can do this .. is it will be secure ?.. If secure . how can i do this.. # pendo

Comment: create a server-side token that expires after one call and pass it with your page...

Comment: @Md.Kamrul Fardaus
What server side language are you using (e,g. PHP/Python/etc)?

Comment: I am using ASP.Net

Comment: Another way altogether would be to create a database table that holds the information you're passing to the iframe.  The including page writes the information that the iframe needs. When the iframe loads, it looks for information in that table.  That way, the information is never present via the UI at all.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with ASP.NET, but I can show you what I'd do with PHP and hopefully that will lead you down the right path.

```
<?php
//contents of the file that includes the iframe
$password = "foo";  //set your password
$key = 123456;  //this is the id that your iframe needs
$encryptedString = openssl_encrypt($key, "AES-128-ECB",$password);  //encrypt the string
?>
<!-- output the iframe and pass the token as a $_GET variabl a la str=$encryptedString -->
<iframe src="iframegenerator.php?str=<?php echo $encryptedString; ?>" />
```

Now here is the iframegenerator.php page

```
//iframe code
$password = "foo";  //set your password
$encryptedString = $_GET['str'];  //get the str variable
$decryptedString = openssl_decrypt($encryptedString,"AES-128-ECB",$password); //decrypt it
echo $decryptedString;  //spit out the contents
```

Make sure you use a strong password, obviously not foo.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try this way.. @pendo